# Como mostrar que o usuário está logado nas páginas que ele visitar?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Como faço para fazer com que o após o usuário fazer o login, que ele possa ver em algum canto da tela o nome dele com algumas informações dele com esse login e que quando ele aperte no botão "voltar" ou "sair" apareça um pergunta se ele realmente deseja prosseguir, e se ele confirma para que ele faça o logout e voltar para o index.

Answer (score 1):

usa as variaveis de sessão do php

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['nome_da_variavel'] = valor da variavel;
```

exemplo:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['nome'] = "joao";
echo $_SESSION['nome'];
```

obs: é possível usar as variaveis declaradas por sessão em várias páginas, elas sao armazenadas enquanto o browser estiver aberto, oque facilita em sistema de login.

e para sair, ou voltar, basta usar o

```
session_destroy();
```

que acaba/destroi todos os valores das variaveis da sessao